# What is the learning rate status when applying keras model fit() iteratively?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I am applying **[keras model fitting](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit)** iteratively (within a for loop) due to a large dataset. My goal is to split the dataset into 100 parts, read each part at once and apply the **[fit()](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit)** method.

**My Question**: In each iteration, does the [fit()](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit) method begins from the *initial learning rate (lr=0.1)* which I set during model compilation? Or it remembers the last updated learning rate and apply it directly on a new call of the **[fit()](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit)** method.

My code sample is as follows:

```py
# Define model
my_model()

# Set the optimizer
sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-08, momentum=0.9, nesterov=False)

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit model and train
for j in range(100):
        print('Data extracting from big matrix ...')
        X_train = HDF5Matrix(path_train, 'X', start=st, end=ed)
        Y_train = HDF5Matrix(path_train, 'y', start=st, end=ed) 

        print('Fitting model ...')
        model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=100, shuffle='batch', nb_epoch=1,
              validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The updated learning rate is remembered in the optimizer object `model.optimizer`, which is just the `sgd` variable in your example.

In callbacks such as `LearningRateScheduler`, the learning rate variable `model.optimizer.lr` is updated (some lines are removed for clarity).

```py
def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
    lr = self.schedule(epoch)
    K.set_value(self.model.optimizer.lr, lr)
```

However, when `decay` is used (as in your example), the learning rate variable is not directly updated, but the variable `model.optimizer.iterations` is updated. This variable records how many batches have been used in model fitting, and the learning rate with decay is computed in `SGD.get_updates()` by:

```py
lr = self.lr
if self.initial_decay > 0:
    lr *= (1. / (1. + self.decay * K.cast(self.iterations,
                                          K.dtype(self.decay))))
```

So in either case, as long as the model is not re-compiled, it will use the updated learning rate in the new `fit()` calls.